# Upload Image file and send to rest API

Tags: javascript, html, django, angular2-template, angular2-services

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';  
import { Http, RequestOptions, Headers, Response } from '@angular/http';  
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';  
@Component({  
selector: 'my-app',  
templateUrl: './app/app.component.html',  
styleUrls: ['./app/styles/styles.css']  
})  
export class AppComponent {  
private isUploadBtn: boolean = true;  
constructor(private http: Http) {  
}  
//file upload event  
fileChange(event) {  
debugger;  
let fileList: FileList = event.target.files;  
if (fileList.length > 0) {  
let file: File = fileList[0];  
let formData: FormData = new FormData();  
formData.append('uploadFile', file, file.name);  
let headers = new Headers()  
headers.append('Content-Type', 'json');  
headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');  
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });  
let apiUrl1 = "/api/UploadFileApi";  
this.http.post(apiUrl1, formData, options)  
.map(res => res.json())  
.catch(error => Observable.throw(error))  
.subscribe(  
data => console.log('success'),  
error => console.log(error)  
)  
}  
window.location.reload();  
}  
}
```

```html
<div class="fileUpload btn btn-primary" *ngIf="isUploadBtn">  
<span>Upload</span>  
<input type="file" id="btnUpload" value="Upload" (change)="fileChange($event)" class="upload" />  
</div>
```

I have implemented the above code, which is handled by a Django REST API. But it shows 415 status code that is Unsupported media type...!

While when I send the same request through POSTMAN it accepts.
Postman Curl command is

```
curl -X POST \
     http://192.168.1.223:8010/profilepic/ \
     -H 'authorization: Basic OTc5Nzk3OTc5NzoxMjM=' \
     -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
     -H 'content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW' \
     -H 'postman-token: 0e6c2353-5a24-2223-d4f3-b8d74c334a3d' \
     -F datafile=@/home/ashwini/Pictures/step4.png
```

My curl command is

```
curl 'http://192.168.1.223:8010/profilepic/' \
     -H 'Origin: http://192.168.1.144:4200' \
     -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' \
     -H 'Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6' \
     -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36' \
     -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=AaB03x' \
     -H 'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*' \
     -H 'Referer: http://192.168.1.144:4200/' \
     -H 'Connection: keep-alive' \
     --data-binary 'datafile=@/home/ashwini/Pictures/step4.png' \
     --compressed
```

Answer (score 0):

Your content type is different on your curl command and the JS call you have.

Comment: plz check above curl commands..1st is accepted and 2nd which is not accepted

Comment: The first curl command has an auth header but the second one does not. You also have the -F switch in the first one but not the second which means you are emulating a form in the first but not the second. I'm not sure that's the problem but it's something to look into.

Comment: @evenflow58 I think you are right on the POST vs GET verb being a problem.